What's the WCTC of this algorithm?
void M3(int N, int M){
 if(N > 0)
     M3(M, N - 1) ;
 else if(M > 0)
     M3(M - 1, N) ;
}

Noting that the recursive call parameters are reversed
I believed it's
min(N,M)
but i just couldn't figure it
one of my friends said that its actually ,o(N+M)

Word Cutting Tour Conference? Or Waukesha County Technical College?

That shit will never terminate. It will get stuck in the else causing a stack overflow.

Assuming M and N are both non-negative, It stops when both parameters are 0, and it subtracts one from one of the positive ones at each step. So it takes N+M steps.

You can add code that counts steps to the existing code, and run it to experimentally verify.

gcc with -O3 will run this code in O(1): https://godbolt.org/z/5GE3P6Pqc

@Tarik Oh yes, it will terminate

@SupportUkraine You are right

Your friend is correct as long as we assume non-negative arguments.
When both arguments are greater than zero, then the recursive calls will decrement them alternately due to the argument swap. One decrement per call. When one argument becomes zero, then the non-zero argument will be decremented once per recursive call. The recursion stops when both arguments are zero. So the number of recursive calls will be N + M + 1.
It's quite easy to test. One way is to add a global variable and increment it for each call of the function.
#include <stdio.h>

int cnt;

void M3(int N, int M){
    ++cnt;
    if(N > 0)
        M3(M, N - 1);
    else if(M > 0)
        M3(M - 1, N);
}


int main()
{
    int N;
    int M;

    N = 21;
    M = 21;
    cnt = 0;
    M3(N,M);
    printf("N=%d M=%d caused %d calls\n", N, M, cnt);

    N = 2;
    M = 39;
    cnt = 0;
    M3(N,M);
    printf("N=%d M=%d caused %d calls\n", N, M, cnt);

    N = 39;
    M = 2;
    cnt = 0;
    M3(N,M);
    printf("N=%d M=%d caused %d calls\n", N, M, cnt);
    

    return 0;
}

Output:
N=21 M=21 caused 43 calls
N=2 M=39 caused 42 calls
N=39 M=2 caused 42 calls

From this it's quite easy to see that the number of calls is N+M+1. In Big-O that is simplified to O(N+M).
However, for negative inputs things will change. If both are negative you have O(1). If just one is negative you have O(non-negative argument)
p.s. As your function is not doing anything "visible" the compiler may turn it into a simple return so that it's always O(1) regardless of arguments.

I can see it now , yes it's O(N+M) , because N will  decrement until it becomes zero and then it's value is passed to M to get out of the if statement ... And the opposite will happen with else so that's why it's O(N+M)

I'd like to point out that "I've tested the program on some cases and saw those cases confirm my hypothesis" does not constitute a proof.

The algorithm is equivalent to this non-recursive formulation:
while (N > 0 && M > 0) {
    if (N > 0) N--;
    else M--;
    swap(N, M);
}

From this, you can see that at each step, one of N and M is decreased if positive (preferring N), and then N and M are exchanged.
Since at each step something positive gets decremented by 1 until both values are non-positive, it immediately follows that this loop executes max(0, N) + max(0, M) times.
